# Decorators and Private fields javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript, decorator, private, class-validator

I find myself trying to use decorators with the native javascript private properties (#) and these first 'recognize' that are in use do not work.

I identified this by using the [class-validator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/class-validator) decorators  on the private properties of my value objects.

The error I get in my code editor is: **Decorators are not valid here**

Example:

```js
import { IsString } from 'class-validator';

Class Person {
  @IsString()
  #name: string;

  constructor(name: string) {
    this.#name = name;
  }

  get name(): string {
    return this.#name;
  }
}
```

Comment: Private fields in JS are *completely* private and inaccessible to anything from outside. Thus it makes sense they cannot be decorated - there is no way for the decorator to access them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okey as suggested by VLAZ:

> Private fields in JS are completely private and inaccessible to anything from outside. Thus it makes sense they cannot be decorated - there is no way for the decorator to access them.

This is completely correct, so when I took a closer look at the value object I realized that it does have public `get` properties, so by testing it is possible to use decorators on those properties.

Leaving something like:

```js
import { IsString } from 'class-validator';

Class Person {
  #name: string;

  constructor(name: string) {
    this.#name = name;
  }

  @IsString()
  get name(): string {
    return this.#name;
  }
}
```